# Accessing variables globally

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have been creating a WordPress plugin which basically creates step by step tours on how to change any settings in WordPress. I was able to get most of the other things done, but the most complicated logic is how to check **if the tour is running and if it is, get the current step and process it ..**

I have been considering options like:

- Setting `global` variables
- Using `history.pushState();`
- Using `wp_options`

Please give your expert opinions on how should I get this done ..

Answer (score 1):

If this is a javascript based tour there's really no reason to bother with retaining the state in WordPress. See [Spooky Action at a Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance) for why relying a global variable is a bad idea in general.

Your problem can be more easily solved by just retaining the state of the tour in a cookie using javascript. Libs like [intro.js](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/) offer pretty convenient APIs for managing all of this easily in javascript.

Comment: The lib you gave is running the tour on the same page, my tours run from page to page. Like step 1 would be page 1 then step 2 would be on page 2. That's why I need variables which can be accessed till the tour is running ..

Comment: If you want specific solutions to specific problems you'll need to ask more than just a general question ;)